# Mysql temp tables are dropped between executions

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, temp-tables

I want be able to debug easily my scripts in MySQL, like in SQL Server (run a chunk of the script then verify the tables and so on), but the temporary tables are not persisted on the server.
For example :

```
CREATE temporary table a(i int);
INSERT INTO a VALUE (1);
SELECT * FROM a;
```

If I run the whole script it returns me the right result, but if I run it statement by statement on the insert I get the following error:

> SQL.sql: Error (2,13): Table 'test.a' doesn't exist

I suppose this is a server configuration problem.

Comment: What are you using to execute the queries? If you're putting them one by one into a tool chances are it's closing the connection in between.

Comment: I use dbForge Studio Express

Comment: One for [@Devart](http://stackoverflow.com/users/135566/devart), I guess.

Comment: Try running the set of queries directly via command line MySQL. I'll bet it works fine.

Comment: If your queries are separated and in fact making new connections for each one, you will need a different approach. You can either 1. check for the table's existence and make a new one if it's not there or 2. (if you need the data to stay in the table for multiple queries) you will have to make an actual table instead of a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary tables are dropped when the transaction is over.**

c.f. [dev.mysql:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

> **Temporary Tables**:
> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a
> table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection,
> and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means
> that two different connections can use the same temporary table name
> without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY
> table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the
> temporary table is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have
> the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.
>
> Note CREATE TABLE does not automatically commit the current active
> transaction if you use the TEMPORARY keyword.

So if you run all these SQL statements in different transactions your temporary table won't exist when you run the insert statement.

Whether these executions are executed in different transactions depend on what interface you use. Thats why if you "run the whole script it returns me the right result" because its all in the same transaction.

You can try to force it to run on the same transaction with:

```
START TRANSACTION;
<SQL QUERYS>
COMMIT;
```

Anyway I recommend to you **MySQL Workbench**  as interface.

Comment: I think you are mixing a "transaction" with "session" in this case. Temporary tables are *not* dropped when the transaction is over but when the **session** is over.